# How to add the value of an input to a li list?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I am trying to add the value of an input as a `<li>` to a `<ul>` list.

I was able to add it by binding the value to the array list of lis. However, it doesn't stay there when I clean the input field. How can I fix this?

HTML code:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="addNewTodo">
    <input type="text" v-model="todo.task">
    <button type="submit">Add todo</button>
  </form>

  <ul>
    <li v-for="todo in todos" :class="{ completed: todo.isActive }" @click="$set(todo, 'isActive', !todo.isActive)">
     {{ todo.task }} <span v-on:click="deleteTodo">{{ todo.delete }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'List of things to do today',
    todos: [
      { task: 'Have breakfast', delete:'(x)'},
      { task: 'Go to the gym', delete:'(x)'},
      { task: 'Study Vuejs', delete:'(x)'}
    ],
    todo: {task: '', delete: '(x)'}
  },
  methods: {
    addNewTodo: function(){
      this.todos.push( this.todo );
    },
    deleteTodo: function(){
      this.todos.shift( this.todo )
    },
  }
});
```

Here there is a sample JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mercenariomode/gwd34815/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the object reference, but in your case, it would be better to bind the "v-model" to the "task" property

Html code:

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="addNewTodo">
    <input type="text" v-model="task">
    <button type="submit">Add todo</button>
</form>
```

JS Code:

```
el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'List of things to do today',
    todos: [
      { task: 'Have breakfast', delete:'(x)'},
      { task: 'Go to the gym', delete:'(x)'},
      { task: 'Study Vuejs', delete:'(x)'}
    ],
    task: '',
}
```

and in the addNewTodo method implement the logic of adding an object to the array

```
addNewTodo: function(){
        let todo = {task: this.task, delete: '(x)'};
        this.todos.push(todo);

        this.task = ''; // clear data in input
},
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nm29yq7d/1/

Answer (score 1):

You're always referencing that property, you should clone it properly like :

```
 let t={};
 Object.assign(t,this.todo)
 this.todos.push( t );
```

Another issue that i see in your code is you're deleting the wrong todo, to fix that just pass the index of the selected todo to the `deleteTodo` method as follows  :

```
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(todo,i) in todos" :class="{ completed: todo.isActive }" @click="$set(todo, 'isActive', !todo.isActive)">
      {{ todo.task }} <span v-on:click="deleteTodo(i)">{{ todo.delete }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

and use `this.todos.splice(i,1);` to delete the given todo :

```
 deleteTodo: function(){
      this.todos.splice(i,1);
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code, it doesn't seems to work. Do you mind doing a sample JSfiddle?